# How do I modify a style so that it will appear as a section heading in a Table of Contents?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I'm creating a document in which I have used `Heading 1` for chapter titles and `Heading 2` and `Heading 3` for sections within a chapter. Then I realize that I'd like to break the document into Parts, so I created a `Heading 0` style.

How can I get `Heading 0` to appear in a generated Table of Contents (and appear in the correct place - as a super-heading over `Heading 1` as well as the Navigation pane?

Comment: I don't think they is a way to do this. The right way to do that is to  `add 1` to all of your Headings

Comment: Except then I would also have to re-define all of the heading styles to look like the ones that replace it... i.e., make the new thing I'll call Heading 2 look just like the original Heading 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work by doing the following:

1. Create a new style called 'Heading 0'.
2. In the modify style dialog select 'Heading 1' as the style based on.

When I updated my TOC Heading 0 appears above Heading 1.

[image: Add Heading 0]

To indent Heading 0 in the TOC, insert another TOC which will overwrite the current one but choose a few options while doing so:

1. Start on the References tab
2. Click Table of Contents
3. Click 'Insert Table of Contents' (select word phrase at bottom not TOC graphic in drop-down)
4. In the TOC dialog click Options (lower right corner).
5. Heading 0 and Heading 1 will both have a '1' for their TOC level. Edit TOC levels so each one is incremental (0 = 1, 1 = 2, ...).
6. Click 'OK' for the Do you want to replace the selected table of contents?

[image: Change TOC levels]

Comment: So, I've got that... but notice in your Table of Contents that Heading 0 and Heading 1 are at the same level. Is there a way to say that Heading 0 is the "parent" of Heading 1 ... that Heading 1 should indent by one level?

Comment: Hey David, I tried to update my original answer. I edited it but received a msg another user must review and approve/reject it. The forum let me approve my own answer but I'm not sure if it appears just for me or if you can also see it. I'm new here - still figuring out the process.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to directly modify the level of ANY style in word.
In the style ribbon, right-click on the style you created (or any other style). Click modify. At the bottom left, you'll see a "Format" button. Click it. Choose "Paragraph".

[image: Screenshot of the dialog in question, with the Format menu opened and the Paragraph item highlighted.]

Make sure you are on the "Indents and Spacing" tab. You'll see an option called, "Outline level". Click the drop down box. Choose what level you want your heading to be (eg., Heading 5 might be at level 5).

[image: Screenshot of the Paragraph dialog, with the Outline Level menu opened and “Level 1” highlighted.]

I do this to my "caption" styles when I write papers and make them level 4 so at least they show up in the navigation pane.

This is likely the most painless way to do it!