# Why is a new style in Word in Office 365 is always considered a heading or subheading?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

For images descriptions, I have created a new style in MS Word (Word in Office 365),. In “View > Navigation” also in the “Table of Contents,” those descriptions are considered as headings and appeared as document sections.

I have also tried creating a new style from scratch but the same thing is happening. I have also checked [this other Super User thread](https://superuser.com/questions/768047/how-do-i-modify-a-style-so-that-it-will-appear-as-a-section-heading-in-a-table-o) but the suggested options are not available in online Word in Office 365.

So, how can I define a new style without being considered as a heading or sub-heading in Office 365?

Comment: Word Online and the Desktop applications are different programs. Not everything that can be done in the desktop applications can be done in the online version.

Comment: There are some differences in the functionality of online and desktop programs.